# Mongoid invalid find error rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid

I understand that this error is coming from the find method within my controller but i am not too sure how to go about fixing the error. I am trying to create a complete method so via checkboxes posts can be archived and removed from the index page. The routes as of yet do not have :id within the relevant complete admin diagnostics so i was wondering if it was also a problem here. Also i am using rails 3.

**Error**

Mongoid::Errors::InvalidFind in Admin::DiagnosticsController#complete

```
    Problem:
  Calling Document.find with nil is invalid.
Summary:
  Document.find expects the parameters to be 1 or more ids, and will return a single document if 1 id is provided, otherwise an array of documents if multiple ids are provided.
Resolution:
  Most likely this is caused by passing parameters directly through to the find, and the parameter either is not present or the key from which it is accessed is incorrect.
```

**view**

```
    %h1 Diagnostics

%table
  %tr
    %th
    %th User
    %th Message
    %th Device
    %th RELS-Mobile Version
    %th Submitted
    %th Archive
  - @diagnostics.each do |diagnostic|
    %tr
      %td
        %strong= link_to 'show', admin_diagnostic_path(diagnostic)
      %td
        - if diagnostic.user
          = link_to diagnostic.user.email, [:admin, diagnostic.user]
        - else
          unknown
      %td
        = diagnostic.data["message"]
      %td
        %pre= JSON.pretty_generate(diagnostic.data["device"])
      %td
        = diagnostic.data["appVersion"]
      %td
        = diagnostic.updated_at
      %td 
        = check_box_tag 'A Checkbox', method: :put, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" }



= link_to 'Save', complete_admin_diagnostics_path, method: :put, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" }


= paginate @diagnostics
```

**controller**

```
class Admin::DiagnosticsController < Admin::BaseController
  before_filter :diagnostic, :except => [:index]

  def index
    @diagnostics = DiagnosticInfo.all.order_by(:created_at.desc).page(params[:page]).per(50)
  end

  def show
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json { render json: @diagnostic }
    end
  end

  def update
    if @diagnostic.update_attributes(params[:diagnostic_info])
      redirect_to admin_diagnostic_path, notice: 'Successfully updated.'
    else
      render action: "edit"
    end
  end

  def edit
  end

  def destroy
    diagnostic.destroy
    redirect_to admin_diagnostics_path
  end

  def complete
    @diagnostic.update_attribute(:completed_at, Time.now)
    redirect_to @diagnostics, notice: "Todo item completed"
    return
  end
  # def complete
  #  DiagnosticInfo.update_all(["Archive=?", Time.now], :id => params[:diagnostic_ids])
  #  params[:diagnostic_ids]
  #  # redirect_to admin_diagnostics_path
  # end

  private

  def diagnostic
    @diagnostic = DiagnosticInfo.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check `params[:id]` is not `nil`